# I get a 404 not found when I navigate to my route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I have a Controller called help in my project like this:

```
    public class HelpController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Help
        public string Index()
        {
            return "test help";
        }
    }
```

This is my route.config file

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ProductsApp.App_Start
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes (RouteCollection routes)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

My Global.asax

```
using ProductsApp.App_Start;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ProductsApp
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

When I navigate to the /Help/Index, I get a 404 server error. If I navigate to /Help. My app instantiates the Home controller. What could be wrong?

Comment: Needs more info. What you've put looks correct so there must be something missing

Comment: Install [Nuget Package Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Help Page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/5.2.3). This can show you a nice page with a listing of all the available routes and their parameters which is very helpful when you start off and are getting 404 errors due to bad configurations or maybe type-os.

Comment: Is your HelpController  is in root area? or you have created other area and added controller in to it? Show your folder structure as well

Comment: The Help controller is in the controller folder. I actually installed that nuget package. Then I tried to set its help controller as the default application page in my project. While running it, I got a forbidden error. So reversed the changes I made but I still got a forbidden error when I navigate to /help

Comment: What's the full URL you are attempting to browse to when accessing the Help controller method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you have Areas > HelpPage inside your web? Maybe this is beign called instead of your controller.

You can implement attribute routing, with them, you can specify what is the route of that controller and method, instead of the RouteConfig.

In my opinion, this approach keeps the code more maintanable and easy to understand. And you can even, use it to make versions of your controllers.

this is an exemple of how you can achieve Attribute routing:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/network/account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{login}"), HttpGet]
    public Account GetAccountByLogin(string login)
    {
        // Code Logic Here
    }
}
```

And how you call this method? you will not type **yourapi/api/Account/GetAccountByLogin/userlogin** because your api or mvc won't recognize that url, instead, it will recognize it when you type: **yourapi/api/v2/network/Account/userlogin**.

These inks can help you:
For areas:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas

For Attribute Routing:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2